# Correctly deducing boundary conditions for Legendre Polynomials

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, boundary-conditions

I'm working on Jackson 3.1 and scratching my head as to why my approach doesnt work.  The problem is

> Two concentric spheres have radii $a, b$, $(b > a)$ and each is divided into two hemispheres by the same horizontal plane.  The upper hemisphere of the inner sphere and lower hemisphere of the outer sphere are maintained at potential $V$.  The other hemispheres are at zero potential.  Determine the potential in the region $a \leq r \leq b$ as a series in Legendre polynomials.  Include terms at least up to $l = 4$.

From this prompt, I immediately deduced the following boundary conditions:

1. $\Phi(a,0 \leq \theta < \pi/2) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(A_{l}a^l + B_{l}a^{-l-1}\right)P_l(\cos\theta) = V$
2. $\Phi(a,\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(A_{l}a^l + B_{l}a^{-l-1}\right)P_l(\cos\theta) = 0$
3. $\Phi(b,0 \leq \theta < \pi/2) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(A_{l}b^l + B_{l}b^{-l-1}\right)P_l(\cos\theta) = 0$
4. $\Phi(b,\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(A_{l}b^l + B_{l}b^{-l-1}\right)P_l(\cos\theta) = V$

Now here's where my issue starts.  I consider the upper-half of the sphere, which corresponds to boundary conditions (1) and (3).  From these two BCs I get

$$A_ma^m +B_ma^{-m-1} = \frac{V(2m+1)}{2}\int_{0}^{1} P_{m}(\cos\theta)d(\cos\theta)$$

and

$$
B_m = -A_ma^{m+2}
$$

From here, I combine the two equations to effectively eliminate $B_m$ from the general solution.  I then take the same approach from the lower-half of the sphere, again eliminating $B_m$.

This leads me to the wrong solution, and I don't understand why.  The correct solutions available online seems to never apply boundary conditions (2) and (3) above corresponding to the grounded parts of the sphere, leaves the solution in terms of $A_m$ and $B_m$, and solves the system of equations to find both coefficients.  I don't see why we can't use these 2 other BC's to eliminate $B_m$ in favor of $A_m$, and clearly I have something wrong.

Comment: You can make things a lot more symmetric by shifting the total potential by $V/2$.